# In a spark streaming application, where is mapWithState executed?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

In a spark streaming application, where  is mapWithState executed? 
Is it on a driver or executor?

Answer (score 0):

`mapWithState` is executed on each of the executors. It is a shuffle stage which causes keys to be mapped to executors, and then each executor executes the stateful function supplied to `StateSpec.function`.